# Is there a function in Python to fit data vector into a (X,Y) table?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a function in Python to fit the data vector like below into a 2D table with X and Y bins. I have been searching for something like that for a long time, but found only a few closed-source programs where it is called "Histogram view".

```
X; Y; Z
2; 16; 0
3; 20; 1
2; 22; 1
3; 21; 2
2; 22; 2
2; 30; 3
2; 35; 5
3; 40; 5
4; 42; 4
5; 43; 3
6; 39; 2
6; 37; 2
7; 35; 3
9; 30; 4
6; 17; 4
7; 13; 2
9; 11; 1
```

The effect I want to achieve is a table like below
[Generated table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H20Pe.png)

| X/Y | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **10** | 0,0 | 0,0 | 2,9 | 1,4 | 1,0 |
| **20** | 1,2 | 1,5 | 3.6 | 1,8 | 1,0 |
| **30** | 3,2 | 2,0 | 2,4 | 3,7 | 4,0 |
| **40** | 5,0 | 4,1 | 2,3 | 3,0 | 4,0 |
| **50** | 5,0 | 3,6 | 3,0 |  |  |

The problem is with data that don't fall exactly into bins like for example line "7; 35; 3" - it is between 6 and 7 for X and between 30 and 40 for Y. I'm looking for some kind of reverse interpolation method to use all of measures to generate the table.

Any pointers how this could be done, greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Why you don't put it in 2D list (nested lists) or use `pandas.DataFrame` eventually in `numpy.array` - this is standard method for `Data Science` in Python. You should see `pandas.DataFrame` in every tutorial for `Data Science`. BTW: your data looks like CSV file (comma separated values) and you can read it with `pandas.read_csv()`

Comment: if you want to display it like in Excel then you would have to write some GUI program. People usually work with data in text mode which can't display GUI or in Jupyter which can display similar table using HTML. Eventually you could display `pandas.DataFrame` using [pandastable](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataexplore.html)

Comment: Yes, so the problem is with data that don't fall exactly into bins like for example this line "7; 35; 3"
It is between 6 and 7 for X and between 30 and 40 for Y.
I'm looking for some kind of reverse interpolation method to use all of measures to generate the table.

Comment: it seems I didn't understand your problem. You have to edit question and better describe problem. And put data as text, not image

Comment: Your generated table makes no sense to me. I don't see the relationship to your data and I also don't see how a table of that type would be useful for anything. The problem may not be how to build it, but that it shouldn't be built at all.

Comment: This table has been generated with the data analysis tool, it needs a lot more data than the snippet I pasted here for the table to make sense https://www.efianalytics.com/MegaLogViewerHD/histograms.html

Comment: I think you will need to provide a bit more of background. I do not think there is even a python question in this, this is more of logic behind some method. Are you binning data together? Maybe create another row between 30 and 40 with value 35 and has all values empty except for column 7

Comment: From the link you shared I see that you are doing histogram. And your question is where to insert values that are right in the middle of the bins. One option like I said before is to create more bins. Another that we were taught in school is to round up number that are in the middle (e.g. round(1.5) = 2). So you can round 7 to 8 and 35 to 40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to fit it in a 3rd degree polynomial. The blue is the given x, y, z points and the red is the x, y, new_z points. The approximate function is in the objective(), see the code below.

##### Output

```
z = 0.02589 * x ^ 3 + -0.43303 * x ^ 2 + 2.17399 * x + -0.00030 * y ^ 3 + 0.02214 * y ^ 2 + -0.40954 * y + 0.51728
a: 0.02589, b: -0.43303, c: 2.17399, d: -0.00030, e: 0.02214, f: -0.40954, g: 0.51728

prediction:
x: 4, y: 42, z: 3.566527711031233
```

[image]

##### code

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


x = [ 2,  3,  2,  3,  2,  2,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  6,  7,  9,  6,  7,  9]
y = [16, 20, 22, 21, 22, 30, 35, 40, 42, 43, 39, 37, 35, 30, 17, 13, 11]
z = [ 0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  5,  5,  4,  3,  2,  2,  3,  4,  4,  2,  1]


# our objective function
def objective(V, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
    """
    r = a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d*y^3 + e*y^2 + f*y + g
    """
    x, y = V
    r = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d*y**3 + e*y**2 + f*y + g
    return r


popt, _ = curve_fit(objective, (x, y), z)

# parameter values
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = popt

print(f'z = {a:0.5f} * x ^ 3 + {b:0.5f} * x ^ 2 + {c:0.5f} * x + {d:0.5f} * y ^ 3 + {e:0.5f} * y ^ 2 + {f:0.5f} * y + {g:0.5f}')
print(f'a: {a:0.5f}, b: {b:0.5f}, c: {c:0.5f}, d: {d:0.5f}, e: {e:0.5f}, f: {f:0.5f}, g: {g:0.5f}')
print()

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(x, y, z, 'blue')
z_new = [objective((i, j), a, b, c, d, e, f, g) for i, j in zip(x, y)]

plt.plot(x, y, list(z_new), '--', color='red')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

# Prediction
print('prediction:')
x = 4
y = 42
z = objective((x, y), a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
print(f'x: {x}, y: {y}, z: {z}')

plt.show()
```